# Is there a way to wear this special armor as a costume?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

During the last quest of the base game's main story (God of Schemes) you use…

> … the amulet of kings to transform into a badass super mega daedric killer-wall melting-god slayer hero and... not kill... but beat Molag Bal. (www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fmIPy7XTUY - I removed the link because it would show what's inside the spoiler tag)

I recently did the quest again on a new char and I realized it looked pretty good.

What I'm looking for is if there exist any way to have my character look like it did then. I haven't seen an option in crown store, and no transformation was added after completing the quest.

So... any way? Or it was like "here... fore 10 min you look awesome. then... get back to your 'eh' looking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meridia's gift to the Vestige manifests itself mimicking the cyrodiilic **Emperor's Regalia**, which is also closely associated with the Amulet of Kings.

[image: Screenshot of the Emperor's Regalia]

So it is indeed possible to obtain this costume, but it won't be easy, all it takes you is to:

## Become Emperor in Cyrodiil

Comment: Well... I think next month I won't go to work any more :).